# Синий екран (смерти?!)

Tags: windows-10

Установил Windows 10. После установил CCleaner, 350 security, нашол 3 вируса. Я их удалил, 350 security. После перезагрузки компьютера выдает синий экран с кодом ошибки (код остановки `inaccessible boot device`);

Что делать?

Comment: После 360 security попросил))

Comment: установить вин10 снова с оригинального дистрибутива, и не использовать вышеуказанный софт.